# back button doesn't close the app

Tags: android, back-button

i'm working on some app with viewpager and its fragments.the problem is that back button doesnt work when its used to close the app.but in other cases it works.is there any wrong code here or a trick to close the app.

edit:I even overrided onbackpressed method and just put a toast message in it instead of finish(); but again the toast message didnt appear.

this is my main activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MaxMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int numOfPages = 3; //viewpager has 4 pages
    private final String[] pageTitle = {"STUDY", "MENU", "QUIZ"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_max_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPages; i++) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(pageTitle[i]));
        }

        //set gravity for tab bar
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), numOfPages);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener(viewPager));


    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_max_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(final ViewPager pager) {
        return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

And this is main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

edit:
some where i read this problem is common for old api's working with new L affairs.whats your idea?

Comment: You might be missing some tags that might help you narrow the type of answer you want to get.

Comment: Remove your overridden `onBackPressed()` method, as it is just performing the default behavior anyway.

Comment: `public void onBackPressed() {
       finish();
    }` why would you do that?

Comment: I add void onBackPressed(){finish();}  for testing.even without this code problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

You should not override onBackPressed, read in docs:

> Take care of popping the fragment back stack or finishing the activity
>   as appropriate.

It is true app is not getting killed immediately, OS takes care about such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to override the onBackPressed() remove the override 
then override the onStop and call onBackPressed from inside of it
read something about android lifecycle you will get it

```
@Override
protected void onStop(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onStop(savedInstanceState);
    onBackPressed();
}
```

Give it a try tell me if it works

Comment: The parameter savedinstancestate causes error.how I can modify it?

Comment: the error says onstop() in appcompatactivity cant be applied to (android.os.bundle)